# Using cpio command to compress directory and move it

Tags: cpio

I want to make /lib/modules compress copy  and move to /opt directory.
using `cpio`

I try this

```
 cpio /lib/modules > directory.cpio | mv directory.cpio /opt
```

Comment: any particular reason you want to use age old `cpio` ? (besides cpio is not a compress tool)

Comment: cd /lib/modules | ls  | cpio -ov > directory.cpio like this

Comment: why not `cd /lib/modules ; ls | cpio -ov > /opt/directory.cpio` then ? (note the `;` after `cd`)

Comment: this ? find /lib/modules > iraklsssi.cpio | cp iraklsssi.cpio /opt

Comment: `;` is used to separate commands, while `|`is used to pipe previous command's output to next's input, it can also separate command, but if they produce not output, execution will halt.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a compressed cpio archive using file to locate the input files**

Backup up some files:

```
find *.txt -depth|cpio -oc|gzip -q -9 -c >/tmp/a.gz
```

List the contents:

```
gzip -d a.gz -c|cpio -it
```

Extract the contents:

```
gzip -d /tmp/a.gz -c|cpio -imVd
```

I grew up creating backups and software distributions on 8" mag tapes to be sent by courier around the world. I still have great love for cpio and find, but my memory is significantly jaded. I'd have used compress/uncompress, but I did not find these in the RHEL7 that I use in the office.  Zcat works just as well, because these are pretty much the same thing nowadays.